# whats app web automation sent button issue in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to send whats message with python selenium. The Message sent button automation is not working. Below is the code..

```
button=driv.find_element_by_class_name('_3M-N-').click()
print('pass _3M-N-')
```

[Send button xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzqTj.png)

Comment: There is a type in `driv.find_element...` should probably be `div`.

Comment: what is the error you are getting, please post error details also.

Comment: whats app web save button automation click is not working.Please check the attached screen shot

Answer (score 1):

You should try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("// xpath")`

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify more details as to what error you're getting and how you located the "driv" variable.

worked for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.app span[data-icon='send']").click()
```

Comment: It is not working man.May i asking for your contact no.Please help me